# Android phone/tablet and computer does not recognize the 2d lidar connected by type-C

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, android

We are using a lslidar m10 which has a type C interface. It can be connected to the USB A port on a computer and work fine.
[image]

Now we look to use the lidar with an android tablet/phone which only has a type C port. But connecting the lidar to the phone does not work.

What is the cause for this problem?

Our attempts: a. We connect the lidar to the type C port on the computer. The lidar's LED light does not turn on. And no response shows on the computer ports. To my knowledge, the type C port usually has a higher voltage level than USB A. So the voltage should not be a issue.
[image]

b. We connect the lidar to the USB A port on the computer, but the connection is achieved by a cable from type C port of the lidar to another type C, and then the USB A port. In this case, the lidar works fine.
[image]

c. We connect the lidar to the type C port on a smartphone which can be connected a USB hub and read from thumb drives on the hub. This time, the lidar does not work as in case a.

I has been in touch with the customer support of lslidar, but they just say we don't support type-C connection. I wonder why this is the case since we have all the necessary ingredient as shown by test case b.

I searched the internet for possible answers, esp. stackoverflow, but to no avail. I expect to find the reason behind the problem so we may connect the lidar to the computer or a smartphone via the type C port.

Update 1:
I tried the approach suggested by @justme, ie, first convert the type C to USB A, and then connect to lidar. It works as shown by the below pics. However, I recall doing the same before and it did not work. I will attribute that to my lousy memory.

[image]
[image]

Updates 2:
I tried the above approach with [unitree lidar L1](https://m.unitree.com/LiDAR/), i.e., first type-C to USB A, then USB-A to type C on the computer. The computer can recognize the lidar. But the computer does not recognize it if I directly connect the lidar's type C port to the computer's type C port. There must be some underlying principles unknown to me, a layman. But this piece of knowledge is enough for me to complete projects so far.
Similarly, I connected it to my android phone, redmi k40 pro.

Comment: A higher voltage can absolutely be a problem--too high of a voltage will destroy your device. But you are also incorrect in that "type C usually provides higher voltage than type A"; it *can*, but it iinitially provides the same 5 V that every other USB device runs on unless and until the device on the other end specifically asks for higher voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means what they say to you, they do not support Type-C port even if their device has Type-C port.

And you seem to be using
an adapter plug with Type-A plug and Type-C receptacle - that is not defined and allowed by USB standard, as it allows dangerous configurations - in your case, it forcibly feeds 5V to the Lidar adapter even if it does not signal it needs power, so with that kind of adapter you can damage your laptop if you accidentally make a mistake and connect it incorrectly.

They designed the Lidar adapter board with Type-C connector but made an error so it was designed without required electronics to be compatible with Type-C connections. This happens if you simply replace e.g. a MicroUSB connector with Type-C connector on PCB.

If the Type-C connection is implemented incorrectly, it does not work at all on Type-C port, or might work only when cable is plugged in with one side up but not with the other side up.

The basic thing is, a laptop with Type-C receptacle keeps VBUS off and monitors if something is plugged in or not. If a laptop can't detect that something is plugged in correctly, it will not output VBUS to a device.

It works on a Type-A port because Type-A to Type-C cables can't disconnect power or detect connections and will forcibly give 5V VBUS to the incorrectly designed Type-C device.

It might not be possible to easily modify the board to work properly, if the connector or PCB does not have the required pins easily available. It only needs two resistors to CC pins to work.

It might be simplest to have two adapters, a Type-C plug to Type-A receptacle, and then a Type-A plug to Type-C plug as that you know will work.

Or you can simply use another USB UART adapter that is comptible.

Comment: I will try this approach "a Type-C plug to Type-A receptacle, and then a Type-A plug to Type-C plug", and come back soon.

Comment: If the downvotes were explained, I would improve my answer. But the fact is, the lidar vendor says Type-C is not supported and it works behind an adapter that forcibly powers it, it really means that the adapter is missing the CC resistors for detecting what's connected.

Comment: I personally think your explanation of the problem is convincing, but I don't know why they deduct the answer's points.

Answer (score -1):

I can't download any information on the https://www.lslidar.com/?documents=single-line-lidar site without providing contact details, but found  [M10 Navigation & Obstacle Avoidance LiDAR Manual V1.1](https://globalgpssystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/1.-LSLIDAR_M10_User-Manual_V1.1.pdf) on a different site. This shows that:

1. The communication with the Lslidar M10 is Standard serial port (baud rate: 460800 bps)
2. The HY2.0-6P adaptor board with the USB C connector performs a UART to USB conversion.

While the USB interface chip on the adaptor board isn't described, given the 460800 bps serial output from the Lslidar M10 the USB on the adaptor board is likely to only support USB 2.0 or 1.1

The [USB-C receptacle pin usage in different modes -> USB 2.0/1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB_2.0/1.1) section on Wikipedia contains:

> A simple USB 2.0/1.1 device mates using one pair of D+/D− pins. Hence, the source (host) does not require any connection management circuitry, but it lacks the same physical connector so therefore USB-C is not backward compatible. VBUS and GND provide 5 V up to 500 mA of current.
>
> However, to connect a USB 2.0/1.1 device to a USB-C host, use of Rd[[57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#cite_note-66)] on the CC pins is required, as the source (host) will not supply VBUS until a connection is detected through the CC pins.

Suspect that the lack of Rd on the CC pins on the USB C connector on the HY2.0-6P adaptor board is why the Lslidar M10 doesn't receive any power when directly connected to a USB C port on a computer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will look into it later on.